# Create NAT64 Network

Tags: ios, ipv6

I have MacOS 10.11 Beta 3 (El Capiton) installed and want to test my iPhone app in IPv6 only NAT64+DNS64 configuration. But I am unable to find the "Create NAT64 network" option in my "Network sharing" dialog.

Has anyone faced this issue? Is there a way to enable this?

Thanks for your  help in advance.

Comment: Do you have a "Create IPv6 Only Network" option? I believe it may have been renamed.

Comment: this is related to programming as it's the option apple recommends for testing ipv6 transition for your apps ... that being said, the option is hidden, you have to hold Option when selecting internet sharing :|

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may help:  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4971  It covers the topic you described.

Comment: Thank you. Had to press "OPTION" button when clicking on the Sharing/Internet-sharing menus. Missed that :P